# Using a present progressive verb as a conjugation substitute in a compound sentence?

Tags: formality, colloquialisms

I realize this is mostly used in colloquial English. I am not much of a grammarian.
I have seen examples of this sentence structure more and more frequently in formal writing. Is it acceptable? If not, how do I re-phrase it to make it acceptable?

> The ventral surface of the (species) lacks uniformity, being slightly blue in larvae and deep red with spots in adult individuals.

Comment: What is it about this structure that makes you doubtful?

Comment: Yes, it's perfectly acceptable, but  _being_ is not a progressive auxiliary here, but the head of a non-finite clause functioning as an adjunct. It's clearly an adjunct since it is portable -- for example it could be fronted, or occupy a medial position. More specifically, it is a depictive adjunct adding descriptive information about the ventral surface.

Comment: @BillJ  why is "being" a depictive adjunct? How is "being" descriptive? Doesn't  "slightly blue"  and "deep red" describe the larvae and the adult respectively?

Comment: It's the whole non-finite clause that is functioning as a depictive adjunct.

Answer (score 1):

There is no progressive tense in your example.

There is the present participle *being*: this can also be used to form progressive tenses, but here is used just as a participle.

Partipial clauses like this are very common in writing, but less common in ordinary speech. They are similar in meaning to a relative clause (here, "which is slightly blue in larvae.... ") but not always interchangeable, because they may attach to a different antecedent noun phrase.

A "which" usually to the most recent noun phrase, so the default assumption here would that it would attach to "uniformity". Since this would not make sense, it would be understood as referring to "surface", but it would make it awkward to parse and understand.

A participial clause, on the other hand, usually attaches  to the subject even when separated from it, so "The ventral surface" is the natural antecedent of "being ... " here.